# Is there a downloadable database of full names?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, names

For my data augmentation algorithm I need a list of full names, that being first, middle and last names. I would prefer if the database also had a frequency value for every full name as I need it for machine learning and would like it to be biased towards more common names.

Comment: There are no middle names in many countries. What do you want to do with that? It looks like you question needs an [edit].

Comment: @stanislav-kralin this isn't a duplicate - or at least the answer in the linked question provides a list of surnames and a list of first names, but not a list of full names, and doesn't include middle names.